# how to use dynamic style in modular way in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

how to apply dynamically styles in module.css in react js when useing map skill is array of object is there something wrong here Im getting error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMJPz.png)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please add reproducible code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We can't know what is wrong if we don't see the error, but I think the error is because you wrote

`` ${styles[`styles[`skill${index}`]} ``

rewrite it this way

`` ${styles[`styles[skill`${index}`]} ``

Comment: thanks but the error is second styles is undefind